# How to read the response from a NewSingleHostReverseProxy

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I've created a [reverse proxy](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#NewSingleHostReverseProxy) like this:

```
func ProxyFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://mynetworkserverhere:8957/some/path/here/")
    if err == nil {
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        //????

    } else {
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }
}
```

And invoke it from main:

```
func main() {
   log.Printf("Starting...")
   http.HandleFunc("/", ProxyFunc)
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
}
```

And it works as expected from the client side, but I'd like to read the response from the proxy, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you try to hijack the connection? Or would this be too low level?

Comment: You mean you want to read the response from the proxy in your go server?

Comment: I do, what I want is to read the response form the proxy to save it in cache... :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The net/http package is really flexible. You can replace the [default Transport](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) of the ReverseProxy with your own, which just uses the DefaultTransport. Then you can intercept the RoundTrip call and do whatever you'd like.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    log.Printf("Starting...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", someFunc)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
}

func someFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // change the request host to match the target
    r.Host = "you.host.here:port"
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://you.host.here:port/some/path/")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)
    // You can optionally capture/wrap the transport if that's necessary (for
    // instance, if the transport has been replaced by middleware). Example:
    // proxy.Transport = &myTransport{proxy.Transport}
    proxy.Transport = &myTransport{}

    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

type myTransport struct {
    // Uncomment this if you want to capture the transport
    // CapturedTransport http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *myTransport) RoundTrip(request *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    response, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(request)
    // or, if you captured the transport
    // response, err := t.CapturedTransport.RoundTrip(request)

    // The httputil package provides a DumpResponse() func that will copy the
    // contents of the body into a []byte and return it. It also wraps it in an
    // ioutil.NopCloser and sets up the response to be passed on to the client.
    body, err := httputil.DumpResponse(response, true)
    if err != nil {
        // copying the response body did not work
        return nil, err
    }

    // You may want to check the Content-Type header to decide how to deal with
    // the body. In this case, we're assuming it's text.
    log.Print(string(body))

    return response, err
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. If I consume the body, my final client gets nothing. If I comment the ReadAll invocation it works ( but I don't get the output ) See: http://play.golang.org/p/pu_hCabebY

Comment: That's a good point. I modified my answer to create a new Buffer from the body bytes and wrap it in a NopCloser (so that it implements the ReadCloser interface), and then set the response's Body property. There may be better approaches, but I don't think this is bad.

Comment: Take a look at [golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse). Either it'll do everything you need or provide a complete example of how to copy the response.

Comment: @deft_code Nice, good idea. Looks like they did the same thing I did: write it to a buffer, use a NopCloser, and set the Body property.